# Change source port of NTP requests on router using iptables

Tags: iptables

My ISP blocks outbound udp port 123. This is preventing ntpd from getting ntp updates.  How do I get my router (Asus router running Asuswrt Merlin) to automatically change the port number from 123 to something else?  I tried using the following iptables rule but it didn't seem to work on the router.  The rule works when I put it on the individual Linux machines but I want to avoid doing that on all of them.

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -p udp --sport 123 -j SNAT --to-source :12512
```

I think on my router I would need to do the port change and MASQUERADE at the same time but I don't know if that's possible.

Here is my POSTROUTING nat table entries on my router.  I tried putting the ntp rule first and second.

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    SNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:ntp to::12512
2    MASQUERADE  all  -- !<my external IP>    anywhere
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm late to the party, but had to do something about the same problem myself today. This superuser page was one of the first google results I encountered at when researching the problem, and I figured I'd add a workaround here to save future searchers some effort.

Adding a specialized masquerade rule for NTP traffic, with the `--to-ports` argument to the MASQUERADE target, **before** your normal masquerade rule will force a source port translation:

`iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 60000-61000`

AT&T blocks outbound UDP traffic with source port 123, to mitigate common NTP reflection attacks from compromised machines on customer networks. Destination port 123 is allowed, but most NTP clients use 123 for the source port as well.

You can verify that their filtering is affecting you by running `ntpdate`. If source port 123 is filtered, `ntpdate pool.ntp.org` will fail while `ntpdate -u pool.ntp.org` will succeed. (The `-u` option to ntpdate forces it to use a non-privileged (>1024) source port number.) If both tests fail, or if both tests succeed, then some other issue is at play and this workaround isn't likely to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Using source NAT to rewrite the source port number from 123 would not change the fact that you're still connecting to **remote NTP servers** that listen on **destination** port 123.  When your ISP blocks outgoing NTP traffic they probably block UDP packets to dport 123 and changing the source port won't make a bit of difference.

Simply ask your ISP which NTP servers they provide which you **can** use.

Comment: I don't think they are doing the blocking in that fashion. It seems like they are blocking traffic if the source port is 123 for outbound packets (essentially blocking me from hosting an ntp server). The NTP queries work fine when I use iptables to change the source port on the individual linux machines.  I just want to confirm if I could do it at the router (along with masquerade) so I don't have to do all the machines individually.

Comment: Assuming the ISP has their on NTP servers, would there be a way for me to rewrite the traffic on my router to use those servers instead of updating all the ntpd conf files to use the server?

Comment: Why the upvotes? This doesn't answer the OP question at all. 
This is a well known issue that manifests a lot with ntp, It is due to ISPs blocking traffic FROM privileged ports.
The OP did not specifically write "ISP blocks outbound [SOURCE] udp port 123", but it is very much implied by the iptables example given. Normally on superuser, speculation on what is "probably" happening gets downvoted. :-P

Answer (score 1):

In order for it to work on your router, you need to specifically add your external interface (public internet facing) address to the rule.
Otherwise, you are sending the packet out onto the Internet with your private IP address as source. 
It may be possible that your particular kernel, netfilter version behaves differently. You can verify what is happening with tcpdump.

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -p udp --sport 123 -j SNAT --to-source {PUBLIC_IP}:12512
```

Then (assuming eth1 is your internet facing interface):

```
tcpdump -ni eth1 port 123
```

This is what I have in /etc/firewall.user on OpenWRT:

```
P_IP=`/sbin/ifconfig eth1 | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}'`
/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -I postrouting_rule -p udp -o eth1 --sport 123 --dport 123 -j SNAT --to $P_IP:12300
```

Don't forget to flush the conntrack tables after making changes to the firewall, if you want to see results right away, on OpenWRT:

```
echo f > /proc/net/nf_conntrack
```

Otherwise it can be really confusing what is going on.